# Asynchronous calls to an URL

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am using

```
chrome.tabs.create()
```

to open a new tab in my Google Chrome extension. For debugging purposes, I need to call another URL just before this call that will log the usage.

- this URL is a call only URL and maps to a PL/SQL procedure that logs the data for me, i.e I do not need to wait for the response
- Also, I need to call it in such a way that any errors in this call whatsoever are completely ignored and do not affect the functionality of my addon

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use asynchronous request (Ajax), for instance:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", yourURL, true);
xhr.send();
```

Here's more info: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html

Comment: And if Lazer wants it when "chrome.tabs.create" is successful, you can pass in the callback. `chrome.tabs.create({url: 'blah.com'}, function(tab) { asyncServerDebug('Tab created'); });`