# AJAX calls not completing because the popup closes

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using [some AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402632/asynchronous-calls-to-an-url/6402701#6402701) in my popup on a button click:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", yourURL, true);
xhr.send();
chrome.tabs.create({url:<some url here>});
```

The problem is that the popup closes as soon as the button is clicked, and I think thats why the ajax calls are not completing.

Is this a common issue? What can I do to make sure that the ajax calls have sufficient time to complete?

Comment: i dont know how it's done without using mootools or jquery , but you need to implement the onCompleted and onSuccess  methods before closing the popup

Comment: @Tarek: actually I need the new tab to open as soon as possible (for which the popup has to close). The ajax call should be run in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what a background page was made for. Move your code to a background page into some `myFunction()`, then call it from a popup:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a callback after the request has finished.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", yourURL, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:<some url here>});    
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This onreadystatechange gets called when the server responds to your request.  Did you check to make sure that the callback function is actually being called?  If it is, then your problem lays elsewhere.